# discord.py - bot not responding even though no error messages

Tags: python, discord.py

I just started learning discordpy but i got stuck after my bot wasn't responding even though i followed the documentation and no error messages. The bot is online but doesn't respond to my messages. Im using python 3.8

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()


@client.event
async def onmessage(message):
    message.content.lower()
    if message.content.startswith("hello"):
        await message.channel.send("Hello!")

client.run('token')
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `onmessage` to `on_message`

Answer (score 0):

Change `onmessage` to `on_message`.
Also do `from discord.ext import commands`.
That is what you are missing because in order to use `@client.event` you must have discord.ext imported...Your code should work after that